# Freebase: Format search result to list all properties of object of unknown type(s)

Tags: search, freebase, mql

I'm trying to write a MQL query to format a search result in freebase (the "output" parameter in the search API). I essentially want to find the (simple) values of all the properties of a given search result (without knowing anything about the types of the result a priori). By "simple", I mean only the default properties if the values are complex objects.

E.g., if I search for "Yo La Tengo" and this takes me to the result for "/en/yo_la_tengo", I want to be able to get the group's members (I just need names, not instruments or dates started), albums (again, just names), films contributed to (again, just names), etc.

Is there a simple way to do this with a search output query, **given that I know nothing about the types**? I imagine there's some sort of reflection magic I can use, and I've tried mucking about with "/type/reflect", but I'm not getting anywhere. I'm brand-new to MQL (though I have extensive SQL experience), so this is a little daunting. Any ideas?

**Edit**: So to clarify, I think the problem I'm seeing is due to mediator types like "performance" (an actor in a film) or "marriage". E.g., with a query about [Yo La Tengo](http://freebase.com/api/service/search?limit=1&mql_output=%5B%7B%22%2Ftype%2Freflect%2Fany_reverse%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%5D%2C%22%2Ftype%2Freflect%2Fany_master%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%5D%2C%22%2Ftype%2Freflect%2Fany_value%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%5D%7D%5D&query=Yo%20La%20Tengo), I can see most (all?) information that I'm interested in, but a similar query about [The Muppet Movie]( freebase.com/api/service/search?limit=1&mql_output=%5B%7B%22%2Ftype%2Freflect%2Fany_reverse%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%5D%2C%22%2Ftype%2Freflect%2Fany_master%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%5D%2C%22%2Ftype%2Freflect%2Fany_value%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%5D%7D%5D&query=The%20Muppet%20Movie -- sorry, SO thinks I'm a spammer so I can't make this a link), I don't see Frank Oz reference at all (probably because his performance is referenced instead). Is there a generic way for me to "follow" mediator types to get all their properties? E.g., is there a single output MQL that would allow me to get the actor in a performance (when linked form a film search result) **and** give the the spouse in a marriage (when linked from a person)?

Answer (score 2):

Querying not only every property, but then following those properties another ply deep in the graph for all search results is going to be an incredibly expensive operation.  What is the use case for this?  Do you really have a UI where the user can see and effectively absorb all this information?  To answer the question directly though, it's not possible to unpack mediator types automatically using mql_output on the search API.

I'd suggest combining a basic set of information on the search query with a deeper set of information on a topic that the user has expressed interest (e.g. by hovering over).  This UI experience would be similar to that of Freebase Suggest.

In the years since the question was originally asked there have been some additional useful things added such as the "notable" pseudo-property which lets you see what the topic is notable for.

Of course everyone also needs to be moving to the new API, so the queries would be:
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=%22the%20muppet%20movie%22&limit=1&indent=true

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/the_muppet_movie

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to do this in outright MQL, but you can:

1. Get all the properties of an object or type of object, then
2. Programmatically construct another MQL query to get those objects you want to know more about.

Look at [this example](http://tinyurl.com/348nqps):

```
[{
  "type|=": [
    "/film/actor",
    "/tv/tv_actor",
    "/celebrities/celebrity"
  ],
  "*": [{}]
}]​
```

It grabs all the properties of all objects that have the type **actor**, **tv_actor**, or **celebrity**. When you run it, you'll see all the possible "follow" points you can explore.

This is not exactly what you want, but it should get you closer.